# Remove Cortana cards temporarily

Tags: 8.1, cortana

When I'm using Cortana, often I'll see some news articles recommended (through the suggestion well, not search), read them, and close Cortana. When I re-open Cortana, say an hour later, I'll get excited that there are things in the suggestion well, only to see that the cards are the same as last time.

If this were Google Now, you'd swipe away the cards and they'd automatically reappear when they get new information. (E.g., when the current weather changes, if there are new articles.)

Is there any equivalent in Cortana?

(For a while I tried Cortana's "Hide this news", until I realized that the interests wouldn't unhide themselves. From what I've seen of Windows 10 for desktop, nothing happens when you swipe away a card, so I'm guessing it's the same in Windows 10 Mobile.)